# python 3.6 installation and lib64

Tags: python, installation, 32bit-64bit, python-3.6

I'm trying to install the new Python (3.6, released just a few weeks back) from source on openSUSE 42.2. Everything

```
./configure --prefix /home/paul/2017 --enable-optimizations
make
make install
```

appears to work just fine, but when I call the shiny new interpreter I get this error:

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan  9 2017, 22:01:27)                                                                                                                                     
[GCC 4.8.5] on linux                                                                                                                                                              
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.pythonrc", line 7, in <module>
    import readline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
```

Now, the module is there, it is installed under $PREFIX/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.
Only the interpreter is not looking there (it is completely ignoring lib64, I checked with -vv).

Update: To be clear, this does not only affect readline but everything under lib64, most notably the modules under lib-dynload.

This appears to be a known issue, see [the Python bugtracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue1294959). It's a fairly lengthy exchange ending in

> Is there agreement on what needs doing here?  I'd like to see this into 3.5 before it reaches its 10th birthday :)

This leaves me a bit confused. Is this supposed to be resolved?
I do not remember ever running into this issue before, so I wonder if it is a 3.6 regression.

And obviously, any fix would be most welcome.

Update: for the time being I can work around the issue by symlinking everything under lib64 into lib. Obviously, that is not an ideal solution; at the very least it defeats the purpose of introducing lib64 (being able to have 32 and 64 bit versions side-by-side) in the first place.
I'd much prefer something in a config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opensuse openSUSE:Factory python3x` has patches for that.

Links:
[Python 3.6](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Factory/python36) [Python 3.8](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Factory/python38) [Python 3.9](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE:Factory/python39)

Spec files are usually a good starting point.

Note: the `install` step would install a `python3` in `/usr/local/bin`. Changing that to `altinstall` avoids shadowing the system-wide `python3`.

## Install

Create a `downloads` variable pointing to a directory where all downloaded files ([python source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) and [factory patches](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/devel%3Alanguages%3Apython%3AFactory/python3)) will be saved

```
export downloads=/usr/local/build/downloads
```

In a user writable directory:

```
tar --no-same-owner -xvf $downloads/Python-3.6.4.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.4

patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.6.0-multilib-new.patch
patch -p0  < $downloads/python-3.3.0b1-localpath.patch
patch -p0 < $downloads/python-3.3.0b1-curses-panel.patch

# mind this step, otherwise
# none of the modules in `lib-dynload` could be imported !
autoreconf -i

mkdir build; cd $_
../configure --enable-optimizations --enable-ipv6 \
             --with-fpectl --enable-shared --with-system-ffi \
             --with-system-expat --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
make -j $(nproc)
# altinstall, not install (see above)
sudo make altinstall
```

## Uninstall

To get rid of the installed files:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib64/libpython3.6m*
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib64/libpython3.so
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/python-3.6*
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/python-3.6*
```

## For python3.7

```
tar --no-same-owner -xvf $downloads/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.3
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.7.3-python-3.6.0-multilib.patch
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.7.3-distutils-reproducible-compile.patch
patch -p0 < $downloads/python-3.7.3-python-3.3.0b1-localpath.patch
patch -p0 < $downloads/python-3.7.3-00251-change-user-install-location.patch

# do not forget !
autoreconf -i

mkdir build; cd $_
../configure --enable-optimizations --enable-ipv6 --enable-shared --with-system-ffi --with-system-expat --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions

make -j $(nproc)

sudo make altinstall
```

## For python 3.8

```
tar --no-same-owner -xvf $downloads/Python-3.8.1.tar.xz
cd Python-3.8.1/
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.8.1-F00102-lib64.patch
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.8.1-F00251-change-user-install-location.patch
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.8.1-SUSE-FEDORA-multilib.patch
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.8.1-distutils-reproducible-compile.patch
patch -p1 < $downloads/python-3.8.1-python-3.3.0b1-localpath.patch

# do not forget !
autoreconf -i

mkdir build; cd $_
../configure --enable-optimizations --enable-ipv6 --enable-shared \
             --with-system-ffi --with-system-expat \
             --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
make -j $(nproc)
# altinstall, not install (see above)
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Sorry, somehow must have missed your answer when you wrote it.

Comment: Thanks, no need to apologize; the answer itself was one year late :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution: If one configures with the `--enable_shared` option the problem somehow goes away. Good enough for me.

Comment: `--enable_shared` was not recognized, and `--enable-shared` did not fix anything (for python-3.6.4, on `openSUSE 42.2`). Actually, none of the `python3.6/lib-dynload/` modules were importable.