# Python 3: Installing gi package with pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to run [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/toolmanager.html) Matplotlib example using Python 3. To run this I needed to install `gi` first (I am using `pyenv`):

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.1
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
$ pip install gi
Collecting gi
  Downloading gi-1.2.tar.gz
Collecting requests (from gi)
  Downloading requests-2.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 959kB/s 
Collecting idna<2.6,>=2.5 (from requests->gi)
  Downloading idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->gi)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 (from requests->gi)
  Downloading urllib3-1.21.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (131kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->gi)
  Downloading certifi-2017.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (375kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 284kB/s 
Installing collected packages: idna, chardet, urllib3, certifi, requests, gi
  Running setup.py install for gi ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2017.4.17 chardet-3.0.3 gi-1.2 idna-2.5 requests-2.16.0 urllib3-1.21.1
```

Now, running the example:

```
$ python toolmanager.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toolmanager.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3cairo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import backend_gtk3
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 10, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
    print url
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Seems like `pip` somehow installed a Python 2 version? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, `pip install gi` will install another unrelated package, the correct
name is `pgi`. But after running:

```
$ pip uninstall gi
$ pip install pgi
$ python toolmanager.py
[...]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "toolmanager.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3cairo.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import backend_gtk3
  File "/home/hakon/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
```

It seems that `pygobject` for Python 3 cannot be installed from PyPI. So I tried to install everything from the Ubuntu distribution package `python3-gi` instead:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-gi
$ pyenv local system
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
$ python3 toolmanager.py
```

and this works fine :)

Comment: How did you know that the correct package is `pgi`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work (anymore): `python3: can't open file 'toolmanager.py'`

Answer (score 16):

The [chosen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214237/3926735) is a little bit outdated as of now:

- Last update of pgi in 2018
- Since 2018, PyGObject is available for python3 from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject/).

Installing the relevant package, plus its dependencies, depending on your environment, is still possible, just follow the [steps from the doc](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

But if you work from a venv, you might still stumble upon a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`  when importing `gi`. The venv ignores the system-wide module. Then simply run, from your venv: `pip install PyGObject` (or use `poetry` or your favorite python packages manager). Of course, you still need to have installed PyGObject's dependencies (see the link to the doc, right above).

Answer (score 5):

To install for the standard python, [Håkon Hægland answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214237/3565696) is the best choice.

But for an [alternate python version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129516/3565696),
one can use `pip<version>`.
Beware that the alternate pip has to be used to match the alternate python.

The full explanations are given in the [documentation](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#opensuse-getting-started).

For instance on openSUSE (standard python version 3.6, alternate installed 3.8):

```
> sudo zypper install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel gcc gobject-introspection-devel
> pip3.8 install --user pycairo
> pip3.8 install --user PyGObject
> python3.8
Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb  1 2020, 14:50:41) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem with an gradio app. The solution

```
Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860

To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gradio/routes.py", line 508, in predict
    output = await route_utils.call_process_api(
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gradio/route_utils.py", line 218, in call_process_api
    with utils.MatplotlibBackendMananger():
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gradio/utils.py", line 817, in __enter__
    self._original_backend = matplotlib.get_backend()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1275, in get_backend
    return rcParams['backend']
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 760, in __getitem__
    plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 327, in switch_backend
    switch_backend(candidate)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 342, in switch_backend
    module = importlib.import_module(cbook._backend_module_name(newbackend))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk4agg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import backend_agg, backend_gtk4
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk4.py", line 12, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39
            print url
                  ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(url)?
```

> pip uninstall gi pip3 install pgi

worked for me.