# import gi returns ModuleNotFoundError; apt install python3-gi returns python3-gi is already the newest version

Tags: python, linux-mint, package-management

If I run python it defaults to python 2.7 and `import gi` works OK. If I run python3 `import gi` returns the error. I assumed (wrongly) that apt install python3-gi would force installation into python 3.8 (my latest version), but it seems to be picking up the package in 2.7 and stopping there. How can I force an installation into python 3.8?

```
No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: LinuxMint
    Description:    Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
    Release:    18.3
    Codename:   sylvia
```

EDIT: Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213921/python-3-installing-gi-package-with-pip)

Comment: try _pip3 install gi_

Comment: @Aleksey, I'm getting "no matching distribution found" for both "gi" and "python3-gi"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3: Installing gi package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213921/python-3-installing-gi-package-with-pip)