# How to limit the rightest Gtk.TreeViewColumn's width inside a Gtk.ScrolledWindow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, treeview, gtk3, gtkscrolledwindow

I cannot prevent the rightest column of a `Gtk.TreeView` to expand.

[image: TreeView Column Size Demo]

As the real `Gtk.TreeView` may display a greater number of rows, making it usually somewhat greater than the screen's height, it is embedded in a `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. This is **required**. Without it, attaching an empty grid at the right of the treeview, expanding itself horizontally, would fix the problem. Based on this idea, I've tried a workaround that introduces another difficulty (see below).

I have built a minimal working example from the example from https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treeview.html#filtering, without filtering nor buttons; and the columns are 80 px wide at least (this works) and their content is horizontally centered. This last detail makes the horizontal expansion of the rightest column visible. In the original example, it does expand too, but as everything is left aligned, this is not really visible. I'd liked to keep the columns' content centered, without seeing the rightest expanded.

This example is minimal, but contains some helping features: you'll find clickable column titles, that will display some information about the clicked column in the console; a remove button (works fine, remove the selected rows) and a paste button that allows to paste new rows from a selection (e.g. from selected lines from a spreadsheet, but there's nothing to check the data are correct, if you paste something that does not convert to int, it will simply crash).

**Workaround**

A workaround I've tried consist of gathering both the treeview and a horizontally expanding empty right grid at its right inside a grid that would be put inside the `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. It works, but causes other subtle problems: in some situations, the treeview does not get refreshed (it happens after a while), yet nothing prevents the main loop to refresh the view (there's no other processing in the background, for instance). To experiment this workaround: comment and uncomment the lines as described in the code below; run the program via `python script.py` (if you need to install pygobject in a venv, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71347337/3926735)), notice the rightest column does not expand to the right any longer, select the 3 first rows and press "remove", then from a spread sheet, select 3 lines of dummy integers as shown below and then press "paste". Scroll down to the last rows: you'll see *most of the time* that the 3 pasted lines do not show up, even if it is possible to scroll over the last row. Maybe one of them will show up after some time, then another... (or simply select a row, and they'll show up). Strangely, it happens if one has just removed as many lines as one wants to paste after the removal (3 removed, 3 pasted; or 4 removed, 4 pasted etc.).

Example spreadsheet selection:

[image: spreadsheet selection]

**Question**

So, I'd *prefer* to avoid the workaround (I'm afraid I may find other situations triggering a bad refreshing of the treeview), that I could not fix itself (for instance, setting `self.scrollable_treelist.set_propagate_natural_height(True)` proved useless, maybe I'm not using it correctly though?) and only attach the treeview itself directly in the `Gtk.ScrolledWindow`. How to prevent the rightest column to expand, then?

(I've tried to use a fair amount of setters and properties of the cell renderers, the treeview, the treeview columns, the scrolled window, to no avail. Some of them are still in the code below.)

Any solution using *and fixing* the workaround above would be accepted though.

In any case, the treeview may be scrolled, and lines may be added and removed from it without any refreshing problem.

**Source Code**

```
import gi

try:
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
except ValueError:
    raise
else:
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

# ints to feed the store
data_list = [(i, 2 * i, 3 * i, 4 * i, 5 * i) for i in range(40)]


class AppWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Treeview Columns Size Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        # Setting up the self.grid in which the elements are to be positioned
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.grid.set_column_homogeneous(True)
        self.grid.set_row_homogeneous(True)
        self.add(self.grid)

        # Creating the ListStore model
        self.store = Gtk.ListStore(int, int, int, int, int)
        for data_ref in data_list:
            self.store.append(list(data_ref))

        # creating the treeview and adding the columns
        self.treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=self.store)
        rend = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        rend.set_alignment(0.5, 0.5)
        for i, column_title in enumerate([f'n×{p}' for p in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]):
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(column_title, rend, text=i)
            column.set_min_width(80)
            # column.set_max_width(80)
            # column.set_fixed_width(80)
            # column.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing(1))
            column.set_alignment(0.5)
            column.set_clickable(True)
            column.connect('clicked', self.on_column_clicked)
            self.treeview.append_column(column)

        self.treeview.set_hexpand(False)
        self.treeview.get_selection().set_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)

        # Put the treeview in a scrolled window
        self.scrollable_treelist = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.scrollable_treelist.set_vexpand(True)
        self.grid.attach(self.scrollable_treelist, 0, 0, 8, 10)

        self.scrollable_treelist.add(self.treeview)
        # WORKAROUND
        # Alternatively, embed the treeview inside a grid containing an
        # empty grid to the right of the treeview
        # To try it: comment out the previous line; uncomment next lines
        # scrolled_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        # empty_grid = Gtk.Grid()
        # empty_grid.set_hexpand(True)
        # scrolled_grid.attach(self.treeview, 0, 0, 8, 10)
        # scrolled_grid.attach_next_to(empty_grid, self.treeview,
        #                              Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)
        # self.scrollable_treelist.add(scrolled_grid)
        # self.scrollable_treelist.set_propagate_natural_height(True)

        # Buttons
        self.remove_button = Gtk.Button(label='Remove')
        self.remove_button.connect('clicked', self.on_remove_clicked)
        self.paste_button = Gtk.Button(label='Paste')
        self.paste_button.connect('clicked', self.on_paste_clicked)

        self.grid.attach_next_to(self.remove_button, self.scrollable_treelist,
                                 Gtk.PositionType.TOP, 1, 1)

        self.grid.attach_next_to(self.paste_button, self.remove_button,
                                 Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)

        self.set_default_size(800, 500)
        self.show_all()

        # Clipboard (to insert several rows)
        self.clip = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_PRIMARY)
        self.clip2 = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)

    def on_column_clicked(self, col):
        print(f'col.get_sizing()={col.get_sizing()}')
        print(f'col.get_expand()={col.get_expand()}')
        print(f'col.get_width()={col.get_width()}')
        print(f'col.get_min_width()={col.get_min_width()}')
        print(f'col.get_max_width()={col.get_max_width()}')
        print(f'col.get_fixed_width()={col.get_fixed_width()}')

    def on_remove_clicked(self, widget):
        model, paths = self.treeview.get_selection().get_selected_rows()
        refs = []
        for path in paths:
            refs.append(Gtk.TreeRowReference.new(model, path))
        for ref in refs:
            path = ref.get_path()
            treeiter = model.get_iter(path)
            model.remove(treeiter)
        # print(f'AFTER REMOVAL, REMAINING ROWS={[str(r[0]) for r in model]}')

    def on_paste_clicked(self, widget):
        text = self.clip.wait_for_text()
        if text is None:
            text = self.clip2.wait_for_text()
        if text is not None:
            lines = text.split('\n')  # separate the lines
            lines = [tuple(L.split('\t')) for L in lines]  # convert to tuples
            print(f'PASTE LINES={lines}')
            for line in lines:
                if len(line) == 5:
                    line = tuple(int(value) for value in line)
                    self.store.append(line)


win = AppWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```